# Double Level Drop Down menu on hover not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, jsfiddle

[Here is my fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ehNrE/12/) which has the codes... my problem is that the drop-down menu in level-one works, but the 2nd level dropdown menu doesnot... It doesnt disappear when i take cursor away from the element and take to the 2nd item in the menu..

[image]

What is wrong? My HTML is as below

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="#">Live-Radio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Songs</a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a>
                    <ul class="subnav2">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub21a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub22a</a></li>
                    </ul>                 
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want this kind of html markup for the drop down. You can checkout the detailed codes in the link..... here is some jquery that I think has the problem with (but dono what it is) taken from the code...

JS :

```
//for my second subnav menu

$(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("li ul.subnav2").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav2 on hover
} , function () {
    $(this).find("li ul.subnav2").slideUp('fast'); //Drop down the subnav2 on hover
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target only the `li`s that have a `.subnav2` element as a child:

```
    $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").find('li ul.subnav2').parent().hover(function() {
        $(this).children("ul.subnav2").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav2 on hover
    } , function () {
        $(this).children("ul.subnav2").slideUp('fast'); //Drop down the subnav2 on hover
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehNrE/14/

On a side-note, `.parent().find(...)` is the same as `.siblings(...)`. Also the selectors will perform faster if you remove the tag names (the only reason to keep the tag names is if you need to select only a certain tag type because multiple tag types have the same class or you need to support Internet Explorer 5.5).

`ul.subnav` would change to `.subnav`.